# Separate Mobile site

Tags: mobile

So, I have a customized desktop site. I want to have a separate mobile site, like `m.example.com`.

I want to have a blank theme or pages that I can customize the mobile site.

Any suggestion to how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could enable multisite and set up your mobile version on a subdomain. That would allow you to control both fairly easily.

However it would ultimately be better to just make the original site responsive.

Comment: Exactly. Mobile nowadays often means good bandwidth and high resolution. Meanwhile at home, on an old laptop with 1024x786 …

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Well, my site works more or less like facebook and I really want to control how the data are presented on a mobile for user experience. I will look into multisite. Thanks

Comment: Right, by making the site responsive, the appearance of the site will shift according to a user's screen size (i.e. desktop vs. mobile). Shifting to responsive design will also save you a TON of work both setting up and maintaining multisite.

Comment: Mhmm, but it also means that all the js, php and css will be loaded and slow down the site. I want to minimize all those by setting up a separate site so I can control what is loaded and what is not. I tried a responsive design but it was much more difficult to design a mobile site without affecting the desktop site. Well, I guess I just have to see how this project goes :P

Comment: And you think that loading ALL of wordpress will actually be faster than loading some CSS and JS? Either way, not my project, not my problem. But I strongly, strongly recommend NOT using the multisite option.